# 'float' object is not subscriptable. Looping and saving to csv error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to loop over some list object, and to save the result to `.csv` file.

When I run my code:

```
    for i in dfxz:
           meanVal = np.mean(dfxz[i])
           varianceVal = np.var(dfxz[i])
           skewVal = skew(dfxz[i])
           kurtVal = kurtosis(dfxz[i])
       
           try:
               csv = open('tabel.csv', 'a')
               csv.write(
                   str(meanVal) + ',' + str(varianceVal) + ',' + str(skewVal[0]) + ',' + str(kurtVal[0]) + ',' + '1' + '\n'
            )
           except IOError as error:
               print('failed to print', error)
        
           csv.close()
```

I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-4c672d5a979c> in <module>
      8         csv = open('tabel.csv', 'a')
      9         csv.write(
---> 10             str(meanVal) + ',' + str(varianceVal) + ',' + str(skewVal[0]) + ',' + str(kurtVal[0]) + ',' + '1' + '\n'
     11         )
     12     except IOError as error:

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I already converted my `pandas.DataFrame` into `int` values from `float`, but with no avail.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Either `skewVal` or `kurtVal` isn't a list, so you shouldn't have `[0]` after it.

Comment: What are `skew` and `kurtosis`, are they from `scipy.stats`?

Comment: Yep, they're from scipy stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
meanVal = np.mean(dfxz[i])
varianceVal = np.var(dfxz[i])
skewVal = skew(dfxz[i])
kurtVal = kurtosis(dfxz[i])
```

you extract the values from the list, and here:

```
... str(skewVal[0]) ...
```

and here:

```
... str(kurtVal[0]) ...
```

you try to extract a value in the position `0` from value, so you receive the aforementioned exception.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks mate, this is work for me. Deleting the 0 value. I forgot that I already extract the values from the list.